# is it possible to use normal camera as thermal using RBG color grading?

Tags: python, tensorflow, colors, camera, temperature

I am working on a project of thermal detection(temperature measurement ) but thermal camera are expensive, Is there is any way to do this using *normal camera* , by using *RBG color grading* so to complete it in less cost.

Comment: Yes, you can do it, but it depends on camera specification. And you need to calibrate it (so you need some resistor and thermometer, to check the RGB values, to correlate with temperature. Every camera model is different (and same phone model may have different cameras on different batches). You need access to RAW images (white balancing and other camera artefact will affect the result). So, try it, and check the results: if they are precise enough for your purpose, on on the right boundaries of temperature. Forget room temperatures (external light is higher them radiation)